# I am trying to modify a dictionary value using the exec function

Tags: python, dictionary, exec

I have a dict, named data 
I have a statement that I want to be run by exec.
It applies but don't assign a value (None is a result)

How to make it working?

```py
data {'a': 'b', 'res': {}, 'new': []}

str_ev = "if a == b : data [res]['aa'] = 'bb' and data['new'].append('aa')"

exec(str_ev)
```

---

I expect:

```py
data {'a': 'b', 'res': {'aa': 'bb'}, 'new': ['aa']}
```

---

but the actual output is:

```py
data {'a': 'b', 'res': {'aa': None}, 'new': ['aa']}
```

Comment: You are misusing the `and` keyword. It is a logical operator, not a means of stringing together two operations.

Comment: please correct this line: ``data {'a': 'b', 'res': {}, 'new': []}``

Comment: this code gave me; ``NameError: name 'a' is not defined``, So please correct this

Comment: Why are you using `exec()` to do this in the first place? Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me…

Comment: Thank you all! 
I used exec becouse we store and exchange with some type of code in db due to security reasons

Answer (score 0):

thx to Brian Joseph and  Mohammad Masoumi.
It was a problem with 'and'.